# twitteR and ROAuth R Packages install

Tags: r

I am having some trouble installing the twitteR and RAOuth packages that are up on CRAN.  I have tried a few different ways; under Windows from source, under Ubuntu using RStudio.  I tried the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-twitteR
```

or

```
install.packages("packagename", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Using RStudio and from source under windows, I am getting a non-zero exit status message.

I have installed from source in the past, but my knowledge on the topic is fairly limited.  Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my system info:

```
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first ascertain whether a package exists:

```
 $ apt-cache search r-cran-twitter
```

will return nothing as it is not packaged. There are 2900+ packages on CRAN but 150 (give or take) on in Ubuntu as `r-cran-*`.

So in that you can you can either download from inside R, or use a browser or something like `wget` followed by `R CMD INSTALL`.  My personal favourite is the script `install.r` that is an example in my `littler` package -- try `sudo apt-get install littler` if you want that.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dirk.  I installed your littler package using the command above, but this is where I am not sure where to go next.  Any further help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `sudo cp /usr/share/doc/littler/examples/install.r /usr/local/bin/` followed by `sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/install.r`.  Now you *could* say 'install.r twitteR` -- but there appears to be a missing Ubuntu package `liboauth-dev` so that will not complete.

Comment: But you could still tweet the way my @CRANberriesFeed tweet feeds: using the `blt` command-line tool. See e.g. my blog post in early January.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the system requirements fulfilled? If you try to install `twitteR` package, it will automatically try to install `ROauth` (since it's a suggested package), which depends on `liboauth`. You can download `liboauth` from http://liboauth.sourceforge.net/ (I don't see an Ubuntu package for it, but didn't look that hard).

If you do that, I suspect it will install ok. It's worth saying that I never got the new `ROauth` package to work despite a successful (and tested) `liboauth` installation - always got a "Server did not respond" error. I am about to release a fully R-native oauth package in the next week. I could use beta testers - email me (in profile) if you'd like a sneak peak.