# ROAuth and twitteR, Mac OS X 10.7, R 2.15

Tags: r, api, twitter, oauth

I'm having a very difficult time getting my OAuth to work so that I can make 350 calls per hour to twitter's API.

I have reviewed several other threads with similar topics, but my problem appears to be different:

[twitteR and ROAuth R Packages install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589522/twitter-and-roauth-r-packages-install)

[twitteR and ROAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373157/twitter-and-roauth)

[TwitteR, ROAuth and Windows: register OK, but certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916283/twitter-roauth-and-windows-register-ok-but-certificate-verify-failed)

my code is as follows:

```
    rm(list=ls())
    library("twitteR")
    library("ROAuth")
    requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
    accessURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
    authURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
    cKey = "__________"
    cSecret = "__________"
    Cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=cKey,
                consumerSecret=cSecret,
                requestURL=requestURL,
                accessURL=accessURL,
                authURL=authURL)
    Cred$handshake()
    registerTwitterOAuth(Cred)
```

Despite trying many different versions of the same code, resetting my API key, and even registering a new account and retrieiving a new API key, i continually return this error:

```
    Error in Cred$handshake() : 
    Invalid response from site, please check your consumerKey and consumerSecret and try again.
```

There is absolutely no way this could be an issue with my key/secret. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:

I had already downloaded this new version of ROAuth (http://lists.hexdump.org/pipermail/twitter-users-hexdump.org/2012-February/000059.html) but had not restarted R! duh!